# acquiring the lock of another object on a synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

i'm currently studying the multithreading concept thoroughly and i'v noticed that whenever a `synchronized block` is discussed, the lock on `this` object is acquired. e.g:

```
synchronized(this) {}
```

but, is there any reason to give another object as the argument for synchronized? or is it an inadvisable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example why locking on something else might be beneficial:

```
final List<Object1> firstList = new List<>();
final List<Object2> secondList = new List<>();

// ...

public Object readFromListOne() {
  synchronized(firstList) {
    return firstList.remove(0);
  }
}

public Object readFromListTwo() {
  synchronized(secondList) {
    return secondList.remove(0);
  }
}
```

Here threads can access both lists simultaneously, while a `synchronized(this)` would have locked both calls, even though it isn't necessary.

Btw: a concurrent list will render all this synchronization obsolete

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common object as follows.

```
static final Object lock=new Object();
```

Then you can parse this into synchronized block as follows

```
synchronized(lock){

 }
```

Only requirement here is you have to share common object. Then each path(different object) locked based on this object.

I think you are having issue with why we use other object.

If we want to locked different path by different Threads we have to locked each path. So we have to use third object. Then when one object quires that lock object other threads has to wait until that lock is resealed. But same thread which acquire the lock can continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **third party object as a lock**. Generally such objects can be used **to achieve synchronization to shared resources between different objects**, which will be forced to acquire this third party object lock before executing certain piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
synchronized(this) {}
```

That means  that any other thread that synchronizes on `this` will have to  **release/wait** until you **release/wait** the lock before it can proceed.

```
  synchronized(somethingElse) {}
```

That means the lock happens on now with `somethingElse`.

So there is a clear difference and depends on what you are synchronized.

Comment: i understood the meaning of passing an object as an argument. 
the question was if its practical or not.

Comment: @Tom Sorry for the misunderstanding, Yes. It is. You can use/pass other objects too. It's very common.